# Highlighting as per the Checklist in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

We follow our own defined coding standard as per our checklist, using Notepad++
For example :
1) If we declare any String it should starts with s as follows
String sTest = null;
If it is String Test = null; I want to highlight that as it is not started with s.
For int it should be
int iCount = 0;
2)If StringTokenizer is used instead of FrameworkUtil.split , then also I need to highlight it in Notepad++
Please let me know how can I highlight for the above conditions in Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to highlight those declarations which are not conforming with the convention mentioned. However, you can find all those declarations with the built-in regular-expression search feature of Notepad++. I state here 2 examples for your String type and int type:

```
For type 'String':

(1) Go to the source file
(2) Ctrl+Home to get to the first line of file
(3) Ctrl+F, a search box will appear
(4) In that search box, at left-bottom corner, 
    there is a radiobox named 'Regular expression', select it
(5) Also in that search box, enter the text to search for as: 
    String[\s]+[^s].+

For type 'int':

(1) Go to the source file
(2) Ctrl+Home to get to the first line of file
(3) Ctrl+F, a search box will appear
(4) In that search box, at left-bottom corner, 
    there is a radiobox named 'Regular expression', select it
(5) Also in that search box, enter the text to search for as: 
    int[\s]+[^i].+
```

You can do it this way for other types also, for example you have type 'abc', and the initial character for variable name is 'x' then use this search text:

```
abc[\s]+[^x].+
```

Or if you want to create your own highlighting syntax for Notepad++, try this: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/25/creating-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad.aspx

Comment: I am trying to use "User Defined Language" to highlight those.But I am not getting what exactly I put in the "User Define Dialogue..". If I put regexp int [\s]+[^i].+ its not working.